# Getting invalid argument error with RNN on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

While running my Python code for RNN on a GPU enabled workstation, following error occurred:

> InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op
>   'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered
>   kernels:

```
 [[Node: lstm_1/CudnnRNN = CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input", is_training=true, rnn_mode="gru", seed=87654321, seed2=0](lstm_1/transpose, lstm_1/ExpandDims_1, lstm_1/Const_1, lstm_1/concat)]]`
```

All the versions of imports are updated successfully in my system. 
I am a noobie and help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The error points that you are running the code on CPU, not GPU.

Comment: Yes, but I have a GPU enabled workstation and it is not showing registered.Can you please suggest how to register gpu?

Comment: You don't "register" the GPU, it is automatically detected by TensorFlow if you have a supported GPU, CUDA installed, and tensorflow-gpu installed. Please add more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the GPU installed correctly(check command "nvidia-smi") then make sure you installed gpu version of the framework you are using. such as

```
 sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```